# ImpactJS - variable values valid until passed to class constructor then become NaN

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, nan, impactjs

Sorry for the long post, but i wanted to be as detailed as possible

So i'm creating a plugin with a couple custom `ig.Class` instances. one is a Vector implementation: [Vec2](https://gist.github.com/riceje7/2ff9d278cca5ee0a77e4) then i have a particle class:

```
Particle = ig.Class.extend({
    pos: null,
    last: null,
    init: function (pos) {
        this.pos = new Vec2().mutableSet(pos.x, pos.y);
        this.last = this.pos;
    },
    draw: function (ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#2dad8f";
        ctx.fill();
    }
});
```

next i have this tire function inside another class:

```
tire: function (origin, radius, segments, spokeStiffness, treadStiffness) {
        var stride = (2 * Math.PI) / segments;

        var composite = new Composite();

        // particles
        for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
            var theta = i * stride;
            composite.particles.push(new Particle(new Vec2(origin.x + Math.cos(theta) * radius, origin.y + Math.sin(theta) * radius)));
        }
        var center = new Particle(origin);
        composite.particles.push(center);
        // constraints
        for (i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
            composite.constraints.push(new DistanceConstraint(composite.particles[i], composite.particles[(i + 1) % segments], treadStiffness));
            composite.constraints.push(new DistanceConstraint(composite.particles[i], center, spokeStiffness))
            composite.constraints.push(new DistanceConstraint(composite.particles[i], composite.particles[(i + 5) % segments], treadStiffness));
        }

        this.composites.push(composite);
        return composite;
    }
```

and finally this update function inside the same class as the tire function:

```
update: function (step) {
        for (var c in this.composites) {
            for (var i in this.composites[c].particles) {
                var particles = this.composites[c].particles;
                // calculate velocity
                var velocity = particles[i].pos.sub(particles[i].last).scale(this.friction);

                // ground friction
                if (particles[i].pos.y >= this.height - 1 && velocity.length2() > 0.000001) {
                    var m = velocity.length();
                    velocity.x /= m;
                    velocity.y /= m;
                    velocity.mutableScale(m * this.groundFriction);
                }

                // save last good state
                particles[i].last.mutableSet(particles[i].pos);

                // gravity
                particles[i].pos.mutableAdd(this.gravity);

                // inertia  
                particles[i].pos.mutableAdd(velocity);
            }
        }
        // relax
        var stepCoef = 1 / step;
        for (var c in this.composites) {
            var constraints = this.composites[c].constraints;
            for (var i = 0; i < step; ++i) {
                for (var j in constraints) {
                    constraints[j].relax(stepCoef);
                }
            }
        }

        // bounds checking
        for (var c in this.composites) {
            var particles = this.composites[c].particles;
            for (var i in particles) {
                this.bounds(particles[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

the error i am getting is at this line in the update function: `var velocity = particles[i].pos.sub(particles[i].last).scale(this.friction);` specifically the error is saying that it cannot call method `sub` of undefined. i changed the tire method above to look like this so i could debug it:

```
tire: function (origin, radius, segments, spokeStiffness, treadStiffness) {
        var stride = (2 * Math.PI) / segments;

        var composite = new Composite();

        // particles
        for (var i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
            var theta = i * stride;
            var x = origin.x + Math.cos(theta) * radius;
            var y = origin.y + Math.sin(theta) * radius;
            var pos = new Vec2(x, y);
            console.log(pos);
            var particle = new Particle(pos);
            composite.particles.push(particle);
        }
        var center = new Particle(origin);
        composite.particles.push(center);
        // constraints
        for (i = 0; i < segments; i++) {
            composite.constraints.push(new DistanceConstraint(composite.particles[i], composite.particles[(i + 1) % segments], treadStiffness));
            composite.constraints.push(new DistanceConstraint(composite.particles[i], center, spokeStiffness))
            composite.constraints.push(new DistanceConstraint(composite.particles[i], composite.particles[(i + 5) % segments], treadStiffness));
        }

        this.composites.push(composite);
        return composite;
    }
```

when i log the `pos` variable i get the proper values being output to the console, however if  still get the error. the only thing i can think is that somewhere between where the `pos` variable is created in the `tire` method and when it is passed and assigned in the `Particle` constructor it losses its value and results in the particle having a `pos.x / pos.y` value of NaN which i can see when i log the var `particles` above the error line (`var velocity = particles[i].pos.sub(particles[i].last).scale(this.friction);`). I really have no idea whats going wrong i've tried changing the `Particle` constructor's assignment of the parameter `pos` to assign it multiple ways (through the `Vec2.mutableSet()` method and setting directly. but no matter what I do it still results in a NaN value for the particle.

Can anyone see something that i am not? thanks

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` for array iteration!  Always use a numeric index variable.

Comment: okay, i'm porting VerletJS to an ImpactJS plugin so it's not all my code, just out of curiosity why shouldn't you?

Comment: The `for ... in` construct doesn't guarantee iteration order, and it'll also iterate through non-numerically-indexed properties of the array object. It's just generally considered a bad practice unless you really know that you need to do it that way.

Comment: I think you just need to add some `console.log()` calls to track the updates to your Particle objects.  Probably some math expressions are being contaminated with strings or `null` values.

Comment: i added a `console.log(pos)` as the first line in the `init()` function which logs the proper values from the `pos` parameter, and `console.log(this.pos)` after i assign `pos` to `this.pos` and then the values are NaN  so its how i'm assigning the values that's causing the problem?

Comment: i tried every which way i can think of to assign the values, i changed the default values of `pos` and `last` to `new Vec2()` and that didn't affect it either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out, there was a javascript file being loaded that was overriding the `Particle` class. removed the script tag with the javascript file and all is well